# How do I extract lines between two strings

Tags: perl

I am an absolute beginner in perl and I am trying to extract lines of text between 2 strings on different lines but without success. It looks like I`m missing something in my code. The code should print out the file name and the found strings. Do you have any idea where could be the problem ? Many thanks indeed for your help or advice. Here is the example:

```
*****************
example:
START
new line 1
new line 2
new line 3
END
*****************
```

and my script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $command0 = "";
opendir (DIR, "C:/Users/input/") or die "$!";
my @files = readdir DIR;
close DIR;
splice (@files,0,2);

open(MYOUTFILE, ">>output/output.txt");
foreach my $file (@files) {
    open (CHECKBOOK, "input/$file")|| die "$!";
    while ($record = <CHECKBOOK>) {
        if (/\bstart\..\/bend\b/) {
            print MYOUTFILE "$file;$_\n";
        }
    }
    close(CHECKBOOK);
    $command0 = "";
}
close(MYOUTFILE);
```

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that you are trying to use a flip-flop here, which might work well for your input, but you've written it wrong:

```
if (/\bstart\..\/bend\b/) {
```

A flip-flop (the range operator) uses two statements, separated by either `..` or `...`. What you want is two regexes joined with `..`:

```
if (/\bSTART\b/ .. /\bEND\b/)
```

Of course, you also want to match the case (upper), or use the `/i` modifier to ignore case. You might even want to use beginning of line anchor `^` to only match at the beginning of a line, e.g.:

```
if (/^START\b/ .. /^END\b/)
```

You should also know that your entire program can be replaced with a one-liner, such as

```
perl -ne 'print if /^START\b/ .. /^END\b/' input/*
```

Alas, this only works for linux. The cmd shell in Windows does not glob, so you must do that manually:

```
perl -ne "BEGIN { @ARGV = map glob, @ARGV }; print if /^START\b/ .. /^END\b/" input/*
```

If you are having troubles with the whole file printing no matter what you do, I think the problem lies with your input file. So take a moment to study it and make sure it is what you think it is, for example:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e"$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $_;" file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.I did the changes according to your suggestions above but every time I run the script it prints out entire file instead of lines only in between START and END string. It works only if the START and END string are the boundaries of entire text in the file, if I have something before START and after END it prints entire file. Any idea why ?

Comment: Well, you do `$record = <CHECKBOOK>` and then never use `$record`, which should mean you have tons of errors, and no lines should print. As for why all the lines print, I don't know. It sounds as though you are reading the file in a single line.

Comment: you are right with the $record. I changed it to :  if ($record =~/\start\b/ .. /^end\b/) {
$command0 = $record;
    $found = 1;
   }      
     
if ($found==1) {
      
      print MYOUTFILE "$file;$command0\n";
      $found = 0;
     } ....but still it prints everything :(

Comment: You have failed to understand how the flip-flop operator works. Read [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators). With a statement such as `if (/foo/ .. /bar/)`, the statement returns false until `foo` is found. Then it returns true until `bar` is found. That is the whole point of the operator, so don't use some silly `$found` flag.

Comment: \s in a regex matches whitespace, not s.  stop putting in extra \ unless you know you need them.  you also aren't using /i or the correct case still.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions I will check the source files again and modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're matching a multi-line string, you might need to tell the regexp about it:

```
if (/\bstart\..\/bend\b/s) {
```

note the `s` after the regex.

[Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) says:

> - s
>
> Treat string as single line. That is, change "." to match any
>   character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not
>   match.

Comment: I think that thing with `..` in the middle is supposed to be a flip-flop, i.e. `/\bstart\b/ .. /\bend\b/`.

Comment: Why do you think he's matching a multi-line string? He's clearly trying to use the flip-flop operator.